# Recursive and Primitive recursive functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computability, recursion

According to the book that I'm reading, we can define the $\mu-$recursive functions inductively, as follows:

1. The constant, projection, and successor functions are all $\mu-$recursive.
2. If $g_1, \dots , g_m$ are $n-$variable $\mu-$recursive functions and $h$ is an $m-$variable $\mu-$recursive function, then the composite function $f=h \circ (g_1, \dots , g_m)$ is also $\mu-$recursive.
3. If $g$ and $h$ are $n-$ and $(n+2)-$variable $\mu-$recursive functions, then the function $f$ defined from $g$ and $h$ by primitive recursion is also $\mu-$recursive.
4. If $g$ is a total $(n+1)-$variable $\mu-$recursive function, then the function $f$ defined from $g$ by unbounded minimalization is also $\mu-$recursive.

The definition of a primitive recursive function is the following:

1. The constant, projection, and successor functions are all primitive recursive functions.
2. If $g_1, \dots , g_m$ are $n-$variable primitive recursive functions, and if $h$ is an $m-$variable primitve recursive function, then the composite function $h \circ (g_1, \dots , g_m)$ is also a primitive recursive function.
3. If $g$ and $h$ are $n-$ and $(n+1)-$variable primitive recursive functions, then $(n+1)-$variable function $f$ defined from $g$ and $h$ by primitive recursion is also a primitive recursive function.

The difference between these two definitions is the minimalization, or not??

The minimalzation is the following:

$$f(\overline{x})= \left\{\begin{matrix} 
\mu z(g(z,\overline{x})=0)=\min \{z \in \mathbb{N}_0 \mid g(z, \overline{x})=0\} & \text{ if } ( \exists z) (g(z,\overline{x})=0)\\ 
\text{ undefiniert } & \text{ otherwise } 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

All primitve recursive functions are $\mu-$recursive, but the inverse doesn't hold, right??

Does this statement stand because of the minimalization??

Comment: The answer to "all primitive functions are $\mu$-recursive but the [converse] doesn't hold" is yes. The question "does this statement stand because of minimization?" doesn't make sense in context - what "statement" are you talking about?

Comment: With "statement" I mean that not all $\mu-$recursive functions are primitive recursive. @RobArthan

Comment: In that case, the answer to both questions is "yes". What more do you need to know?

Comment: Could you explain to me further the minimalization?? Why is that the reason that not all $\mu-$recursive functions are primitive recursive?? @RobArthan

Comment: The standard example of a $\mu$-recursive function that is not primitive recursive is the [Ackermann Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function).

Comment: Yes, I am studying the Ackermann's function now. I have read the proof that this function is not primitive recursive. Do you know an online book or a link where I can read the proof that the Ackermann's function is $\mu-$recursive?? @RobArthan

Comment: http://planetmath.org/ackermannfunctionistotalrecursive

Comment: General rule: generally, better to move the `-` character outside dollar signs if it is a hyphen. Inside the dollar signs, it is treated as a minus sigh, which leads to bad spacing. So $\mu$-recursive rather than $\mu-$recursive.